# Proving $4x^2$ is not One-To-One

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Give that $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $f(x) = 4x^2$. Disprove that this is one-to-one.

I am trying to do this without a graph, and by writing a proof. We are told that for a function to be one-to-one it must follow this format: $\forall a,b \in A[(f(b) = f(a)) \rightarrow (b=a)$. So I tried the following:

$$f(b)=f(a) \\ 4b^2 = 4a^2 \\ b^2 = a^2 \\ \pm b = \pm a$$

Now I have the math, but I don't know what this says at the last line. I know squared functions are not one-to-one because the domain maps to more than one codomain, and it fail the vertical line test because of this. How do I say this with the approach of my proof? Like I said before, I don't understand the last line of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

Can you end it now?

Comment: I see. So my last line could be saying something like, "b maps to a plus or minus a?"

Comment: @ E__  We need $x_1\neq x_2\Rightarrow f(x_1)\neq f(x_2),$ but it's wrong. Also, by your reasoning you took $f(a)=f(b)$, but you did not get $a=b$.

Comment: Okay, I think I am understanding this. So for this to be one-to-one it need to be $a = b$ not anything else, like $a \ne b$?

Comment: @E__ Yes, of course.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant to say, "It should say $a = b$, not anything else like $\pm b = \pm a?$ My mistake!

Comment: @E__ Not anything else like $a=-b$.

Comment: Now this is clear! Thank you again!